# Assets(images, css) url resolution for actions in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

what's the best approach for making reference for assets, for nested urls.

e.g. if in my html I refer to image this way: , it does not work when the url is myapp/admin/edit/1 or any custom url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the asset tag helpers, `image_tag` and so on:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Wherever your current path is should make no difference, as accessing assets should be done from root, e.g. `/images/whatever.jpg`, `/stylesheets/whatever.css`

The asset tag helpers will make this transparent, and additionally, they will transform paths for you if you ever use an asset host other than your web server.  For example.

```
# if you define a different asset_host, Rails will handle it.
ActionController::Base.asset_host = "assets.example.com"

image_tag("rails.png")
# => <img alt="Rails" src="http://assets.example.com/images/rails.png?1230601161" />
```